# DIV or jQuery reveal with a slide/reveal?

Tags: jquery, html, slide, expand

I am trying to complete a project to do a reveal on an image so that two other images come out as if they were wings? The example was this:

[image]

I have tried doing it with DIVs and some jQuery but I can only get one to reveal or reveal in the wrong way, like up and down or slide in from the corner, not from the middle.

Anyone know an easy way to do this?

jsfiddle.net/fTJPu/17/embedded/result

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: How would you get the right one to go right, and then also be flush with the main image? and also be off at first and click to be revealed on? I dont know how to add this to the main one, keeps saying it needs a code?
http://jsfiddle.net/fTJPu/17/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery UI slide() functions.

[JQuery UI Slide demo](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

Have the wings with a lower z-index in css underneath the base image and hidden.

Toggle and slide out the wings with the slide function. The API will let you slide left or right with time delays.

A jsFiddle of what you've got would be nice.

Update: Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWYzg/2/). I didn't use tables like you did but divs. It looks a bit cleaner I think. Basically the wings start off hidden and the toggle() will show it. I used the UI slider.

Html:

```
<div class="angelBox">
    <div class="angelBody">
        <div class="leftWing wing"></div>
        <div class="rightWing wing"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <br/><br/>
    Click on the Blue Box
```

CSS:

```
.angelBox{
    margin-left:100px;
}
.angelBody{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:blue;

 }

.wing{
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:grey;
    display:none;
}
.leftWing{
    position:absolute;
    left:-70px;
    top:50px;
}
.rightWing{
   position:absolute;
    right:-70px;
    top:50px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.angelBody').click(function(){
    $('.leftWing').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
    $('.rightWing').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
});
```

The elements are absolutely position but they're in a relatively positioned container so you can move the entire 'widget' to wherever you like.

Comment: How would you get the right one to go right, and then also be flush with the main image? and also be off at first and click to be revealed on? I dont know how to add this to the main one, keeps saying it needs a code? jsfiddle.net/fTJPu/17/embedded/result

Comment: you made a beautiful angel :)

Comment: I never thought about divs! Thank you soo much! This is perfect! Now I just need to change the color and figure out how to apply images and text/links to the wings and I am done!

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, you can usually force the behavior you want with .animate().

I'd probably set up two different animate calls, one on each wing. I'd set the initial width of each wing to be less than that of the base image, set the z-index of the base image higher than the wings, and then do something like this:

```
$('#image2').animate({
    'width': image2Width,
    'left': (leftEdgeOfBaseImage - image2Width)
}, delay);

$('#image3').animate({
    'width': image3Width,
    'left': rightEdgeOfBaseImage
}, delay);
```

Comment: How would you get the right one to go right, and then also be flush with the main image? and also be off at first and click to be revealed on? I dont know how to add this to the main one, keeps saying it needs a code? jsfiddle.net/fTJPu/17/embedded/result

Comment: Edited your fiddle w/ animates I was talking about. CSS places the divs, jquery moves them. http://jsfiddle.net/fTJPu/18/